# Drupal admin tasks throwing 404 after 10 seconds

Tags: drupal

I noticed running some Drupal admin tasks if they take usually more then 10 seconds result in a 404 error. For example, I was running "Search and replace" and it always throws a 404 after about 10 seconds even though the task apparently works.

I only noticed this after migrating my Drupal install to Dreamhost. I've increased the max_execution time in php.ini but that didn't help. Is there a way to get Drupal to output the error?

Apache Error log:

[Wed Jun 30 09:00:18 2010] [error] [client 12.105.246.2] (104)Connection reset by peer: FastCGI: comm with server "/.../cgi-bin/dispatch.fcgi" aborted: read failed, referer: .../admin/content/scanner/scan/confirm

[Wed Jun 30 09:00:18 2010] [error] [client 12.105.246.2] FastCGI: incomplete headers (0 bytes) received from server "/.../cgi-bin/dispatch.fcgi", referer: .../admin/content/scanner/scan/confirm

[Wed Jun 30 09:00:38 2010] [error] [client 12.105.246.2] (104)Connection reset by peer: FastCGI: comm with server "/.../cgi-bin/dispatch.fcgi" aborted: read failed

[Wed Jun 30 09:00:38 2010] [error] [client 12.105.246.2] FastCGI: incomplete headers (0 bytes) received from server "/.../cgi-bin/dispatch.fcgi"

**UPDATE**
Turns out this was a hosting problem with DreamHost. On their basic shared hosting Drupal was hitting their resource/memory limit and getting processes killed. I had to move the hosting to a Dreamhost VPS (PS) as a workaround.

Comment: not really programming related ... maybe this belongs on serverfault?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Check the Error Reporting settings in admin/settings/error-reporting to see if it is writing the error the screen (and log).
2. Check admin/reports/dblog to see the latest log entries.
3. Check the Apache error log.

Comment: #1 Was set to log to screen and log, tho nothing is ever printed to the screen. #2 no errors listed #3 I found the error tho don't know what it means... I've posted the error logs above.

Comment: Turns out this was a hosting problem with DreamHost. On their basic shared hosting Drupal was hitting their resource/memory limit and getting processes killed. I had to move the hosting to a Dreamhost VPS (PS) as a workaround.